# I've been reading The Algorithm Design Manual, but this statement confuses me and I'm not sure how what it says is true

Tags: algorithm

The following statement confuses me:

> The nearest-neighbor rule is reasonably efficient, for it looks at each pair of points (pi,pj) at most twice: once when adding pi to the tour, the other when adding pj.

It's from the following block of text (highlighted in blue):

[image]

Say the pair of points is the 2nd and 3rd, (2,3) how is that pair of points looked at twice? When it adds the 2nd one, it sets the 2nd to be the closest unvisited point to the 1st, then when it gets to adding the 3rd, it looks at the 3rd to be the closest to the 2nd. That's the only point I can see them looking at that point pair.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

They view this more mathematically - there is a set of points and every time a point is added to the tour the whole set is visited for the best candidate. The set is not altered when a point gets added to the tour, the points just get flagged as visited. Therefore every pair is considered twice.

If one actually implements that algorithm you would probably use a set of unvisited points and update this set after each iteration. Now every pair gets visited only once but at the cost of altering the set which may - depending on the implementation - take more or less time than just visiting every pair twice.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but when would it ever take more time with the altering the set method?

Comment: I am sure I can implement an arbitrarily slow set type. :D But even if you - still naively - just use a array based list and perform linear searches and the nearest neighbors are always close to the front of the list and you therefore have to move almost all elements one position towards the front on every remove operation - this will probably be much slower than performing look-ups in a hash table based set without altering the set after each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation says "at most twice".

If they expected every pair to be examined twice, the words "at most" would not be there. A counter-example to "at most twice" would be a pair that is examined three or more times, not a pair that is only examined once.